# Variable-string concatenation in Shell (sh)?

Tags: sh

I want to write a small script that uses a path stored in a variable. Let’s say that path is `foo/bar/`.

If I set a variable `path` to `foo/bar/`, how can I use it with some string appended after it? If I want to output `foo/bar/baz`, I can’t just do `echo $pathbaz` because it looks for a variable `pathbaz`, which doesn’t exist.

If I remove the trailing slash from the variable and set `path` to `foo/bar`, I can then do `echo $path/baz` and correctly get `foo/bar/baz`. **However, is that the only approach? Can I keep the slash inside the variable somehow?**

Here’s output directly from `sh`:

```
# path=foo/bar/
# echo $pathbaz

# path=foo/bar
# echo $path/baz
foo/bar/baz
# exit
```

Comment: `echo ${path}/baz` is the only other reasonable option. Good luck.

Comment: A bit ugly but still correct: `echo "$path""baz"`.

Comment: Also correct `printf "%s%s" "$path" "baz"`.

Comment: I discovered you could simply wrap the variable in curly brackets, like this `${path}baz`.

Comment: yeah, just for fun: `echo "$(echo -n "$path"; echo baz)"`.

Comment: Having recently created some scripting I find that rarely is the endgame to echo out a string, but rather to use it in some way.  A better example of what you want the script to eventually do with this path or variable will probably help save you some pain.

Comment: @gview I use it as an argument to some `git` commands, `cd`, `rm -rf ${path}stuff`. Nothing crazy. I used `echo` to simplify the problem.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov -- to make sure you are clear on what you are doing, the only reason you need `${var}` is to explicitly define the boundary of your variable. There is no need with `$path/baz` because `'/'` cannot be part of a variable name. If however you wanted to separate by `'_'`, then using braces would be required, e.g. `${path}_baz` otherwise the shell would try to dereference the variable named `path_baz` because `'_'` is a valid character in a variable name.

Comment: Yep, I understand. It’s like in PHP. Thank you for your help, people!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the variable in curly brackets:

```
# path=foo/bar/
# echo ${path}baz
foo/bar/baz
# exit
```